# Is there any kind of inverse for the "has" function (contains at least 1) negated to (contains none)

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am looking for all cards where the key has been returned. Closest I have been able to find is the has and hasNot, but hasNot isnt property based.

Trying to get it to be something like this
g.V().hasLabel('card').both().DOESNOTHAVE('keyReturned',false)

A hasAll would work as well

Comment: maybe something like this: `!(g.V().hasLabel('card')).both().DOESNOTHAVE('keyReturned',false)`? I am not familiar with gremlin. Just thinking that it might work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with

g.V().hasLabel("Location").has("Name", "{location}").out("locatedat").not(out("being used by").has("approved", true).has("keyReturned", false))